# BibTex LaTex citation error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, texmaker

I'm new to LaTex. I'm having difficulty citing literature from Bibtex .bib files in LaTex. I use Texmaker as LaTex editor and JabRef as bibliography manager.
Here, I created a sample LaTex file and a BibTex file in Texmaker:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@misc{Linusson2013,
author  = "Henrik Linusson",
title   = "Multi-Output Random Forests",
howpublished = "University of Borås",
year    = "2013",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Tanmoy}
\title{XYZ}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
dajhgdahbsdkfjhsdhsdjknsdnsdjkl 
\subsection{A}
ahbshbcsdgcjbhcjh ~\cite{Linusson2013}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{myreferences}
\end{document}
```

I've enabled the "Pdflatex + Biblatex + Pdflatex(x2) + view PDF" in Quick Build in Texmaker configuration. However, after each PdfLaTex compilation, I get the 'warning'- "Citation 'Linusson2013' on page 1 undefined". Followed by the second 'warning'- "There were undefined citations". On importing references from .bib file generated in JabRef, in addition to the above errors, the statusbar shows- "No file abc.bbl".
P.S.: I've also tried "\citep{}" to the same errors.
P.P.S: I've also tried enabling "Pdflatex + Biblatex + Pdflatex(x2) + view PDF" via terminal, where it gives the error- "I couldn't open filename abc.bib.aux".

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I make 2 seperate files:

A {documentname}.tex file from:

`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} ... \end{document}`

A myreferences.bib file with just:

```
@misc{Linusson2013,
author  = "Henrik Linusson",
title   = "Multi-Output Random Forests",
howpublished = "University of Borås",
year    = "2013",
}
```

Run as Mico suggested: Pdflatex + BibTex + Pdflatex + Pdflatex + Internal Pdf Viewer

Using BibTex in two different documents gives a lot of advantages if you have a lot of references. If you only have a few references consider using the bibliography within the script, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{natbib} No need for this package
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Tanmoy}
\title{XYZ}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
dajhgdahbsdkfjhsdhsdjknsdnsdjkl 
\subsection{A}
ahbshbcsdgcjbhcjh ~\cite{Linusson2013}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{Linusson2013} 
    Henrik Linusson. 
    \textit{Multi-Output Random Forests}. 
    University of Borås, 2013.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```